# Is there a way to restrict the project drop down list when you bind an Eclipse project to a SonarQube project?

Tags: eclipse, sonarqube, sonarlint

My Eclipse project is made up of about a dozen smaller projects.
My SonarQube dashboard shows the main project followed by the subprojects with a single line separation. They all share the same name, but hovering over the name will show the main project or the subproject  [(two hover examples)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQifU.jpg) .

In Eclipse, when I want to bind my project, the list provided from the SonarQube server [(Eclipse bind options screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Msbks.jpg) includes all the subprojects, but they all have the same name.

Is there a way to only show the main project in the bind list or have the subproject name be easier to find both in the bind list and the sonarqube project view?

Answer (score 0):

Currently that's not possible, but it's a good idea.

We plan to implement it and I've created a ticket to track this feature, that you can follow/vote: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLE-94